# Different result on laptop and stationary computer

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

The code below calculates the size of a the rect holding the text to a checkbox. Code works fine when i'm using a stationary computer with monitors with different screen resolution. But when I run the exact same code on a laptop with an external monitor connected the box is too small. Laptop screen res is 1680x1050 and the monitor is 1920x1080.

pclRect has the same values no matter which computer I run it on.

Anybody's got an idea how to solve this?

Results:

[image]
[image]

```
void CForm::SetSize(CWnd *pCWnd, CRect *pclRect)
{       
    CDC *pclDC = m_pclPanel->GetDC();

    CFont* font = pCWnd->GetFont();
    LOGFONT logFont;
    font->GetLogFont(&logFont);

    CString str;
    pCWnd->GetWindowText(str);//Get controller text

    CClientDC dc(pCWnd);
    dc.SelectObject(font);

    int iWidth;
    int iHeight;

    long lFontSize = -MulDiv(logFont.lfHeight, GetDeviceCaps(pclDC->m_hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72);

    iWidth = dc.GetTextExtent(str).cx; //Get controller text length
    iWidth += GetExtraWidth(); //This adds 18 to the width since it's the width of the checkbox itself
    iHeight = abs(lFontSize) + GetExtraHeight();

    pclRect->bottom = pclRect->top + iHeight;
    pclRect->right = pclRect->left + iWidth;

    pCWnd->MoveWindow(pclRect);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If target window is Vista or higher, use [BCM_GETIDEALSIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the minimum size. But check box cannot have multi-line flag (`BS_MULTILINE`). For example

```
m_checkBox.SetWindowText(L"long text xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx");
SIZE sz;
if (Button_GetIdealSize(m_checkBox.m_hWnd, &sz) && sz.cx > 0 && sz.cy > 0)
{
    m_checkBox.SetWindowPos(0, 0, 0, sz.cx, sz.cy, SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOMOVE);
}
else
{
    //use another method ...
}
```

Otherwise, modify your code and instead of supplying `18` pixels for checkbox width, use 
`GetSystemMetrics` to find the check box width (this results in 15 pixels in default DPI, so you have to add few more pixels for text padding).

Use `GetThemePartSize` if theme is active. For example:

```
CClientDC dc(this);
SIZE sz;
HTHEME ht = OpenThemeData(m_hWnd, L"Button");
if (ht)
{
    GetThemePartSize(ht, dc, BP_CHECKBOX, CBS_CHECKEDNORMAL, NULL, TS_TRUE, &sz);
    CloseThemeData(ht);
    //sz.cx is 13 pixels in default DPI
}
else
{
    sz.cx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK);
    //sz.cx is 15 pixels in default DPI
}
```

Screen resolution is not relevant here. The posted images suggest that both displays have the same DPI settings. Note that if DPI settings changes, and your application is [DPI aware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then `sz.cx` will be different.

Comment: Thank you for the response, this helps a lot. But since I use `BS_MULTILINE` I haven't tried the first part. But when I run the second part of the answer I do get different result on `ht`. However, `sz.cx` is 13 in both cases. Am I missing something?

Comment: With the image on the left, it looks like theme is endabled; therefore `ht` is valid and `sz.cx` will be 13. With the image on the right, it looks like theme is not enabled; therefore `ht` is `NULL` and `sz.cx` will be 15.

Comment: You're right about `ht`, valid and `NULL`, however `sz.cx` is 13 whether it's valid or not. But you've helped a lot and I can move on from here. I really appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: I am on Windows 10, in which theme is always active, so `sz.cx` is always 13 (I think Windows 8 is the same). On Windows XP/Vista/7, if theme is not active, `ht` will be `NULL` and `sz.cx` will be 13.